# OpenGL ES object position changes despite 0 translation value

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, matrix-multiplication

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    float[] scratch = new float[16];
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    if(move_x) x=-tiltx/100;
    else{
        x=0;
        if(side_x) {
            if (tiltx < -0.1f) {
                x = -tiltx / 100;
                move_x = true;
            }
        }

        if(!side_x) {
            if (tiltx > 0.1f) {
                x = -tiltx / 100;
                move_x = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(move_y) y=-tilty/100;
    else{
        y=0;
        if(side_y){
            if(tilty <-0.1f) {
                y=-tilty/100;
                move_y=true;
            }
        }
        if(!side_y) {
            if(tilty >0.1f) {
                y = -tilty / 100;
                move_y = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Part above checks if it is allowed to move, if it is not it assigns 0 to translate value (x and y). Than (below) the translation is applied, despite the 0 x or y values it moves the object a little futher more and that causes to object end partly behind the view. It also causes to trigger the

`if (Math.abs(scratch[12])>=2.4 && move_x)`

again when coming back which means playing the sound again.

```
    Matrix.translateM(mBall.mModelMatrix, 0, (float)x*1f, (float)y*1f, 0f);



    // Combine the rotation matrix with the projection and camera view
    // Note that the mMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
    // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mBall.mModelMatrix, 0);

    if (Math.abs(scratch[12])>=2.4 && move_x){
        setMyBoolean(true);
        move_x=false;

        if(scratch[12]<0) {
            side_x=false;
            scratch[12]=-(float)2.4;
        }
        else {
            side_x=true;
            scratch[12]=(float)2.4;
            }
        // true - prawa strona, false - lewa
    }

    if (Math.abs(scratch[13])>=1.8 && move_y){
        move_y=false;
        setMyBoolean(true);


        if(scratch[13]<0){
            side_y=true;
            scratch[13]=-(float)1.8;
        }
        else {
            side_y=false;
            scratch[13]=(float)1.8;
        }
        // true - prawa strona, false - lewa
    }

    mBall.draw(scratch);
```

The code above checks if the object did hits the wall and if it does it blocks futher movement, plays the sound via setMyBoolean, and whats most important - sets the object to exactly touch the wall by changing the scratch[12] and 13 values.

As explained above, in the next loop the object position is calculated different (despite the fact the translate variable is set to 0) and the ball ends in the wall again.

It's worth mentioning that it does not change the position futher in the next loops. It stays in the wall until I tilt the phone to the other side triggering the if that allows the object to move away from the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually simple, my method didn't or actually did work but only from one frame, since I didn't correct the wrong position by translating the object. What I did was only correcting the value of matrix that was used to draw the object once. But since the ball remembers its position, it would still draw iteself in the wall in the next frame.

What I did to fix this issue is by adjusting the position of the ball when I've detected it just hit the wall and didn't yet go back. Now the adjustments are made by actually translating the object and it is done every frame.

Heres the code that does that:

```
if(!move_x) {
        if(side_x) {
            Matrix.translateM(mBall.mModelMatrix, 0, (scratch[12] - (float) 2.4) * 1f, 0, 0f);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mBall.mModelMatrix, 0);
        } else {
            Matrix.translateM(mBall.mModelMatrix, 0, (scratch[12] + (float) 2.4) * 1f, 0, 0f);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mBall.mModelMatrix, 0);
        }
    }

    if(!move_y) {
        if(side_y){
            Matrix.translateM(mBall.mModelMatrix, 0, 0, (1.8f - scratch[13]) * 0.5f, 0f);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mBall.mModelMatrix, 0);
        } else {
            Matrix.translateM(mBall.mModelMatrix, 0, 0, -(1.8f + scratch[13]) * 0.5f, 0f);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mBall.mModelMatrix, 0);
        }
    }
```